# How to reload Jquery or Javascript function without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Is it possible to reload only JavaScript or Jquery function alone or Is it possible to reload the external Javascript file for every 30 seconds instead of reloading the page.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would the *function* change?

Comment: I am trying to reload the script alone for every 30 seconds.

Comment: Quentin, a developer may want to do this while doing a bunch of quick code changes, to avoid having to reload/reset a big page. That's why I was looking for it.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: I've edited my answer since apparently still a few people see and use this. I've added a callback which triggers a reload after 30 seconds just when the `getScript` works. You might want to leave this out or add a `.done()` / `.fail()` callback (have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)), also.
Additionally I've added a random query value to make sure the script, that gets loaded, does not get cached:

```
<script id="myscript" src="src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  var salt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    time;

  function load_script() {
    $('#myscript').remove();
    $.getScript("src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js?s=" + salt, function() {
      $('script:last').attr('id', 'myscript');
      salt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      time = setTimeout(function() {
        load_script();
      }, 30 * 1000);
    });
  }
  load_script();
});
</script>
```

---

Old version:

```
<script id="myscript" src="src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#myscript').remove();
        $.getScript("src/to/file-with-your-custom-scripts.js", function() {
            $('script:last').attr('id', 'myscript');
        });
    }, 30000); // every 30 seconds

});
</script>
```

Comment: this is just a rough idea, it does not take into account what namespaces, variables and so on must be deleted/ taken care of since the OP did not provide ANY information...

Comment: does this script starts the task of the external file every 30 seconds again and again or it just remove and add the file.

Comment: @loyola You cannot remove script from browser memory, you can just overwrite it but still need to take care about any data/event previously bound. So basically, whatever you are trying to do, seems the wrong way. That's said, this answer question as asked

Comment: @Alex This script is working fine. You are awesome man... Keep helping other. Thank you.

Comment: @A.Wolff Actually I am try to sync two image slides. I tried my other ways but I was not able to fix that. The above script works properly for me. I know I am doing in crazy way but I need a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Also to load the live data in our webpage without reloading we can use PHP MVC called **CodeIgniter** with Jquery. Please see the below link to make it easier. Also go to official [website](https://www.codeigniter.com/) and find many more interesting things.

http://chrissilich.com/blog/make-your-own-live-data-feed-with-php-codeigniter-and-javascript-jquery/